# azure-cli doesn't match with azure-cli-core

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, ansible, azure-cli

Installing `azure-cli` doesn't match with the github [requirements.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible-collections/azure/dev/requirements-azure.txt) and it uninstalls most of the packages from github requirements.txt.

Any idea which version of `azure-cli` matches with `azure-cli-core==2.34.0`?

```
azure-cli 2.38.0 requires azure-cli-core==2.38.0, but you have azure-cli-core 2.34.0 which is incompatible.
azure-cli 2.38.0 requires azure-graphrbac~=0.60.0, but you have azure-graphrbac 0.61.1 which is incompatible.
azure-cli 2.38.0 requires azure-keyvault~=1.1.0, but you have azure-keyvault 1.0.0a1 which is incompatible.
azure-cli 2.38.0 requires azure-mgmt-apimanagement~=3.0.0, but you have azure-mgmt-apimanagement 0.2.0 which is incompatible.
```

Comment: Since [`azure-cli-core`'s page](https://pypi.org/project/azure-cli-core/) redirects to the same GitHub repo as `azure-cli`, the obvious trial would be install `azure-cli==2.34.0`, and indeed installing would also install the core package at the same version.

Comment: But even 2.34.0 uninstalls other packages from requirements.txt.

Comment: Then they are not compatible, don't use them both at the same time. Or use a virtual environment.

Comment: Sure I'd rather install azure-cli. But when I try to run ansible-playbook I get the error that there is no module named `azure-cli`.

Comment: Well, then just install azure-cli.

Comment: Can you tell if the following error in the following question means that it is trying to look for `azure.cli` or it can't find `azure.cli.core`?  We can't go with just `azure.cli` lot of issues. We have `azure-cli-core` installed and want to know if the import statement error is due to which package. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73162252/ansible-no-module-named-azure-cli

Comment: No, I can't and no one will be able to, as stated in this other question and also in the one you deleted, you are giving partial information that are nowhere close to the required {mre], Follow the instructions stated on the module documentation, if that still does not do it for you, then make a step by step way to reproduce it if you are still not able to make it work, without all this, your question is doomed to the same fate as the two others.

Comment: Although, you will probably end up with the same answer, the most likely is that you are installing on python2 when your ansible runs in python3 or vice versa